# Regex splitting by a specific character which might be found else where in the string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, string-matching

```
([0-9\*\+-/]+?)([\+-\*/])\?\{((?:(\?\{.*?\}))|(.*?))\}
```

I'm using the above patter to detect a pattern of the form:

```
5+(6/2)+?{5>2,?{2=4|5<6,5,5+6*2},10}}
       ^
```

OR

```
?{5>2,?{2=4|5<6,5,5+6*2},10}}*5+(6/2)
                             ^
```

I'd like to split this expression by the character marked with 
^

Any ideas on how to achieve this, I'm still a noob at regexing.

Thanks in advance

Note: that this part: `([0-9\*\+-/]+?)([\+-\*/])` of the regex is not yet tested. However I can get that to work if it isn't. However what I really want to know is how to split the string. Thanks

Comment: So what are the criteria to detect the character you want to split on?

Comment: that it is before an ?{...} or after an ?{....}

Comment: @Jonny can you show us an example ? do you want to split the string to just 2 parts ?

Comment: hmmm ... That is the example :/. And yes in two parts

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Regex.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) as :

```
string input = "?{5>2,?{2=4|5<6,5,5+6*2},10}}*5+(6/2)";
string[] str;
string pattern = @"(\?{.*})";
str = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
richTextBox1.Text = "";
foreach (string s in str)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += s +"\n"; 
}
```